# Can't use text input

Tags: html, css, input

Why am I unable to click on and type in the text input in the following? And what is the best way to fix this?

```
<body>
    <div class="centralCollumn">
        <div class="NewsTitle">Forum, Ask Questions or give advice</div>
        <div class="NewsHeadBreak"></div>
        <div class="NewsPara">
            <form class="commentForum">
                Leave a comment or question: <input type="text" name="comment" class="comment" ></input>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here's my CSS:

```css
.centralCollumn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 18%;
    left: 10%;
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: #ecf1f3;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LUVbk/ It works here, that means it's a problem with the CSS. Post your CSS.

Comment: `</input>` isn’t valid, but it should work anyways. Could you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that demonstrates the problem, please?

Comment: @JustinColyar: The `z-index: -1` puts it behind its parent, making it impossible to interact with anything on it. You can still see it since the parent’s background is transparent, though. Why do you need the `z-index: -1`?

Comment: Only on .comment and .centralCollumn, .comment is set to 10 and .centralCollumn is set to -1

Comment: just remove the z-index.

Comment: Just did a quick test by creating an html file with this css and can confirm as everyone has already said that if you remove the z-index then it works. @minitech should post an answer as he was first.

Comment: @DanielLee: If you insist! :)

Answer (score 5):

The `z-index: -1;` puts `.centralCollumn` behind its parent, making it impossible to interact with anything on it. You can still see it since the parent’s background is transparent, though. Just take that part out.

Answer (score 0):

Your input tag is incorrect. Try removing...

```
</input>
```

The correct use of a placeholder is...

```
<input type="text" name="comment" class="comment" value="$comment" >
```